# How to get the package of methods or objects in Scala?

Tags: scala

How to get the package of methods or objects in Scala?

For example

```
import scala.math._
round().getClass // errors
```

Is there a way to get the **desired output:** `"scala.math.round"`? So that I can be sure of round() method doesn't come from any other package I've imported.

PS. Without using Intellij IDE. The IDE shows you this info, hence there has to be a function that IDE calls to get this info.

EDIT:
For example, running these commands in scala shell

Comment: When do you want to get this information? Where do you want to get it? The compiler has this information, which is where the IDE gets it from (IDEA uses its own Scala compiler, most other IDEs use the Scala compiler form Lightbend).

Comment: I guess coming from the world of python, the concept of reflection is foreign to me.

Comment: "hence there has to be a function that IDE calls to get this info" Not necessarily there should be a *function*. Compiler knows this, so IDE does. You can run commands in shell https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/c6a24c172f28c2545b00a405cbd8c082

Comment: @SidaZhou Actually you can just try to call method without parameters in shell and compile error will name the package: `error: missing argument list for method round in package math`.

Comment: I guess it helps a bit, it doesnt display the full chain of packages tho.

Answer (score 2):

With Scala reflection (`libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value` in `build.sbt`) you can do

```
import scala.math._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(
      showRaw(reify {
        round(???)
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Output at runtime will be

```
Expr(Apply(Select(Ident(scala.math.package), TermName("round")), List(Select(Ident(scala.Predef), TermName("$qmark$qmark$qmark")))))
```

Or you can add `scalacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-Xprint-types", "-Xprint:typer")` to `build.sbt`.

Then compilation of

```
package pckg

import scala.math._

object App {
  round(???)
}
```

will produce (at compile time)

```
Warning:scalac: package pckg{pckg.type} {
  import scala.math._;
  object App extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): pckg.App.type = {
      App.super{pckg.App.type}.<init>{()Object}(){Object};
      (){Unit}
    }{Unit};
    scala.math.`package`.round{(x: Long)Long}(scala.Predef.???{Nothing}){Long}
  }
}
```